# Fetch Resultset of created&filled MSSQL temp table over Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sqljdbc

query5

```
String query5 ="USE DBTwo\n" +
    "DECLARE @temp_table table (column1 VARCHAR(60))\n" +
    "insert into @temp_table (column1)\n" +
    "select column1 from real_table (nolock)";
```

query3

```
String query3 = "USE DBTwo\n" +
    "select column1 from @temp_table";
```

Connections;

```
ResultSet rs1;
Statement stmt;

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.131.10;" +"databaseName=DBOne;" +"user=" + "exuser" + ";" + "password="+"userpass" + ";" + "allowMultiQueries=true" + ";"; 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
stmt = con.createStatement();
```

Fetching Resultset;

```
   try {
       int rowcount = stmt.executeUpdate(query5);
       System.out.println(rowcount);

       rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(query3);
       while (rs1.next()) {
             System.out.println(rs1.getString(1)); 
       } 
        rs1.close();
   }
   catch (SQLException sqlex){
       sqlex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Sql Exception throw below error;

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Must declare the table variable "@temp_table".`rowcount` return 7
```

so i succesfully filled the `@temp_table`, I don't close `stmt` connection and try to fetch Resultset from this `@temp_table`. But SQL says I have not declared this table yet. How is it possible ?

**-- SOLVED --**

Creating just one query;

```
String query5 ="USE DBTwo\n" +
"DECLARE @temp_table table (column1 VARCHAR(60))\n" +
"insert into @temp_table (column1)\n" +
"select column1 from real_table(nolock)\n" +
"select column1 from @temp_table";
```

Fetch multiple results like below;

```
try {
  boolean result = stmt.execute(query5);
  while (true)
   if(result){
    rs1 = stmt.getResultSet();
    while (rs1.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs1.getString(1)); 
    }

  } else {
    int updateCount = stmt.getUpdateCount();
    if (updateCount == -1){
    break; 
  }
    result = stmt.getMoreResults();
}
catch (SQLException sqlex){
   sqlex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically following the JDBC spec you are only allowed to execute a single statement at a time. That the SQL Server JDBC driver allows the execution of multiple statements in one execute is a deviation of the standard.  Also note that doing things like `USE databasename` is contrary the recommendation in JDBC to use `Connection` methods (like `setCatalog`) for this, as it may bring the driver in an inconsistent state.

As to your specific problem, I have two theories (I haven't verified if these are the actual cause):

1. You have auto commit enabled. After a statement execute, the connection is committed, and the temporary table is disposed.
2. After a statement execute the query context is disposed by the server, so a subsequent execute does not have access to the temporary table.

These are theories, and I believe that 1. is the most likely. So try to disable auto commit (`Connection.setAutoCommit(false)`).

If theory 2. is the cause, then you need to execute them in one go, and process multiple results (a count and a result set). For this you would use `Statement.execute(...)` and process for multiple results. See my answer to [Java SQL: Statement.hasResultSet()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213824/java-sql-statement-hasresultset/14413141#14413141) for an example on how to process multiple results.

This last solution probably also works if you don't want to disable auto commit.

Comment: Theory 2 is absolutely rigt. I know the logic now. Your answer in other subject very clearly. Thanks for the solution.